# How to full-text filter with admin-on-rest on loopback server

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, admin-on-rest

I want to use a fulltext filter with admin-on-rest to query data from my loopback server.
I have tried to implement the example from the documentation ([AOR-doc](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html#filters)), but I have unfortunately only managed to query single fields:

```
const CatFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search" source="CatCode" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
);
```

How can I use a loopback backend to perform a full text search across multiple fields that will search for "contains" string if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this, I am outlining both below.

1) Loopback fulltext search needs a custom Remote Method that does a Regex search.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html

jump to the section for regular expressions.

This was the best way I could find for doing text searches in LB.

This is my filter

```
const AdminFilter = (props) => {
  return (<Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Name Or Email" source="userNameOrEmailId" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>)
}
```

This generates a filter of the following form in the API side.

```
const findUsersByNameOrEmail = (filter) => {
    const regex = '^' + filter.where.userNameOrEmailId
    filter.where.or = [{name: {'regexp': regex}}, {email: {'regexp': regex}}]
    delete filter.where.userNameOrEmailId
    return findAllUsersByFilter(filter)
}

const findAllUsersByFilter = (filter) => {
    return AppUser.find(filter)
}
```

A minor hackyness here I guess would be assigning a dummy source in the filter like userNameOrEmail in above. Though it isnt really overriding any default concerns. Just helping us set appropriate filters.

2) You can also achieve the same thing by doing something like the filter construction that is being done by function findUsersByNameOrEmail above in a custom Rest Wrapper or your own Rest Client. So something like below in your rest Client or wrapper.

```
 if (type === 'GET_LIST' && resource === 'appUser') {
  const regex = '^' + params.userNameOrEmailId
  const url =  `URLroot/filter={where: [or: {name: {'regexp': regex}}, {email: {'regexp': regex}}]
  options.method = 'GET';
  return handleRequestAndResponse(url, options)
}
```

The idea is to intercept the call to your API and fix things as you need beforehand.

Comment: But how can I use regex with admin-on-rest?

Comment: Admin On Rest's only job is to pass a string to the API. it is the job of the custom Remote Method to take that string and pass it to a RegexSearch. Will edit my answer with some more details.

Comment: Just FYI I just had to implement a text /Id based regex search and approach 2 outlined above worked just fine. So you can try that out too if you don't want to get into remote methods.

Comment: I really like your approach, but I'm still quite new to the world of loopback and haven't managed to get your example to work.
The API side must be included in the model. js? How do I link the whole thing so that it is accessible via get model?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi. Loopback is quite analogous to Django if you have ever used that. There is the concept of the remote method like Django views. Read more about it here. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html

Also approach 2 works better in your case. Then you only work with the AOR Client side app.

Comment: If you use approach 2 you can write a custom rest wrapper like shown here https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

Comment: If Rest wrapper approach will probably result in the least amount of code for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I think I found a solution that seems to work well. I hope I have not overlooked any problem so that the solution can help someone else or make me aware of the mistake.
First I created a [Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) in MongoDB

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

In Loopback I created an [access operation-hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html) in die model-name.js that catches the full-text query "q" and makes a direct database query:

```
Clinic.observe('access', function logQuery(ctx, next) {
    console.log('Accessing %s matching %s', JSON.stringify(ctx.Model.modelName), JSON.stringify(ctx.query.where));

    if (ctx && ctx.query && ctx.query.where && ctx.query.where.q) {
      ctx.query.where =
      {$text:
      {
        search: ctx.query.where.q,
        language: "de",
        caseSensitive: false,
        diacriticSensitive: false
      }
    }
    }
    next();
  });
```

The Filter in the admin-on-rest code has remained as in the example:

```
const CatFilter = (props) => {
  return (<Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Full Text Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>)
}
```